# Postgres: Is it possible to show only one entry when duplicate occurs?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a postgres database with duplicated entries. I would like to show the created_by columns and the

```
id | name    | created_on
1  | 'Hello' | 3/29
2  | 'Hey'   | 4/3
3  | 'Hello' | 3/31
4  | 'Hey'   | 4/1
```

As 'Hello' and 'Hey' is duplicated, I would like to form a single query to list the following:

```
id | name    | created_on
2  | 'Hey'   | 4/3
3  | 'Hello' | 3/31
```

How could I form that SQL query?

Actually I tried putting 'DISTINCT ON' and 'ORDER BY' in a single query (with JOIN) it gives me the following error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the data type of `created_on`??

Comment: Actually it is a full date format

Comment: OK See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT name, MAX(created_on) AS MaxDate
  FROM tablename 
  GROUP BY name
) AS t2  ON t1.name       = t2.name
        AND t1.created_on = t2.maxdate;
```

### [SQL Fidle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!10/b7f55/6)

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
select 
  a.* 
from 
  table1 a
inner join 
  (select 
     name, 
     max(created_on) as date 
  from 
     table1 
  group by 
     name)b
on 
  a.name = b.name AND 
  a.created_on = b.date
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/f399e/4)

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!10/b7f55/9)

```
select distinct on (name)
    id, name, created_on
from tablename
order by name, created_on desc
```

If you need it ordered by id:

```
select *
from (
    select distinct on (name)
        id, name, created_on
    from tablename
    order by name, created_on desc
) s
order by id
```